# Rotate final image with projection matrix

Tags: rotation, matrix, projection

I'm trying to use space in my shadow (depth) maps in a more efficient way. If I could freely rotate the final image I get with projection matrix I could save a lot of pixels, but I don't know if it is possible to do so. Is it?

Comment: So you want to roll the shadow map camera?  Of course it's possible; just stick in a Z-rotation matrix between the view and projection matrices.

Comment: will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the shadow map view by inserting a Z-rotation matrix between the view and projection matrices.  This is like rolling the shadow map camera, which causes the resulting shadow map image to rotate in 2D.